# Scrubbing chapters and not losing stop points on audiobooks on iPod nano

Tags: mac, ipod-nano, audiobook

1. Is there a way to scrub through a chapter on the 6th gen nano? I have only been able to scrub chapter to chapter which isn't useful when you become distracted and want to rewind 30 seconds.
2. Is there a way to not lose the stop point in the audiobook when you plug into the computer to recharge battery?  When I connect the nano to my computer to recharge (auto add etc. is all disabled) the place you stopped at is lost.

Answer (score 1):

If it works the same as an iPhone, on the headphone cable press the volume down button (-) 3 times in quick succession and hold it down on the 3rd press. This goes into a rewind mode that rewinds as long as you hold the button down.

You can go into a fast forward mode in a similar manner with 2 presses and hold down.